# Concatenate mp4 video files using ffmpeg on nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg

I'm trying to concatenate several videos using FFmpeg with Nodejs. I'm receiving the "No such file or directory" error. The written code is:

```
const glob = require("glob");

//store all the filenames with path to the videos
var inputVideos = glob.sync("/home/r/clips/*.mp4");
const output = "./output/output.mp4";

const util = require("util");
const exec = util.promisify(require("child_process").exec);

async function concatVideos(inputVideos, outputVideoPath) {
  

  //imported to get the name of videofile easily
  var path = require("path");

  //the next ffmpeger variable,will keep the lines
  //ffmpeg -i videofile1.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts intermediate_videofile1.ts
  //ffmpeg -i videofile2.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts intermediate2_videofile2.ts

var ffmpeger = "";
  ffmpeger = inputVideos
    .map(
      video =>
        ` ffmpeg -i ${video} -c copy
    -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts ./intermediate_${
      path.parse(video).name
    }.ts`
    )
    .join("\n");

  //concatenator keeps the segment
  //"concat:intermediate_videofile1.ts|intermediate_videofile2.ts"
  var concatenator = '"concat:';
  concatenator +=
    inputVideos
      .map(video => `./intermediate_${path.parse(video).name}.ts`)
      .join("|") + '"';

  await exec(
    `
    ${ffmpeger}
    ffmpeg -i ${concatenator} -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc ${outputVideoPath}`
  );
}
concatVideos(inputVideos, output);
```

and the error is

````
concat:./intermediate_0.ts|./intermediate_1.ts|./intermediate_2.ts|./intermediate_3.ts|./intermediate_4.ts|./intermediate_5.ts|./intermediate_6.ts|./intermediate_diegoortiz1399.ts|./intermediate_dog.ts|./intermediate_dogstify.ts|./intermediate_dylan50568.ts|./intermediate_gabrieleecorrea.ts|./intermediate_golden_leo.ts|./intermediate_helenapatiih.ts|./intermediate_kaiobreno2.ts|./intermediate_khancorso.ts|./intermediate_kitakaze_s_lili.ts|./intermediate_oliver45743.ts|./intermediate_pinkie_pets.ts|./intermediate_shibakoma.ts|./intermediate_thepetcollective.ts|./intermediate_tod_the_foxx.ts|./intermediate_userpub3y9m7kb.ts|./intermediate_warriorbulldogs.ts: No such file or directory```

So the command line would be:
````

ffmpeg -i videofile1.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts intermediate_videofile1.ts
ffmpeg -i videofile2.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts intermediate_videofile2.ts
ffmpeg -i "concat:intermediate_videofile1.ts|intermediate_videofile2.ts" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc ./output/output.mp4

Could you help us? Many thanks. Truly.:>

Comment: Use the concat demuxer ([documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat) & [wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#demuxer)) instead of the concat protocol. You can avoid the temporary files with the concat demuxer.

Comment: Thanks [Ilogan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1109017/llogan)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the solution I found is in https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg-concat.

First install:

```
npm i ffmpeg-concat
```

Then:
To concatenate videos:

```
const concat = require('ffmpeg-concat')
const glob=require('glob')

//an array of video path to concatenate
const videos=glob.sync('/home/username/Downloads/clips/*.mp4')

const output='./output/concatenated.mp4'

//a function to merge an array of videos with custom music
//and a transition fadegrayscale of 500ms duration between videos.
async function oneTransitionMergeVideos(){
  await concat({
   output,
   videos,
   audio:"/home/username/Downloads/music/music.m4a",
   transition: {
     name:"fadegrayscale",
     duration: 500
   }
})
}

oneTransitionMergeVideos()
```

It will concatenate a video, with audio, and transitions. Wohooo!!!

Comment: What if someone doesn't want transitions? Looking at the docs, defining one seems necessary (?!)

Comment: Just omit the transition object.

Comment: Thanks. The docs made it seem necessary.

Comment: Or use 0 miliseconds in the duration on the transition's object

Comment: what if the user wants to keep the audio as it is for both the videos like stock concat the audio like the videos

Comment: i had a video with with no audio in the first place in the array which was why i had no audio from the rest of the clips :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [editly](https://www.npmjs.com/package/editly)

```
npm i editly
```

Concat videos like this:

```
const clips = [
{
    layers: {
        type: "video",
        path: "path/to/clip1.mp4"
    }
},
{
    layers: {
        type: "video",
        path: "path/to/clip2.mp4"
    }
}
];
await editly({
    keepSourceAudio: true,   //to keep audio
    outPath: "./data/merged.mp4",
    clips: clips,
    //lot's of other great features
});
```

(I've spent a long day on ffmpeg and other non-nodejs solutions as well,this one is fare the easiest solution, altho using ffmpeg directly might be faster)